# How to manage return values of an unknown amount of Callables using ExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, callable

I want to create a singleton-ExecutorService with a fixed threadpool size. Another thread will feed that ExecutorService with Callables and I want to parse the result of the Callables (optimally) immediately after the execution is done.

I am really uncertain how to implement this properly.
My initial thought was a method in the singleton-ES, which adds a Callable to the ExecutorService via "submit(callable)" and stores the resulting Future inside a HashMap or ArrayList inside the singleton. Another thread would check the Futures for results within a given interval.

But somehow this solution does not "feel right" and I didn't find a solution for this usecase elsewhere, so I am asking you guys before I code something I regret later.
How would you approach this problem?

I am looking forward to your responses!

Comment: You might try call method Future.get() from other thread, that will be blocked while Callable is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class PostProcExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

  // adjust the constructor to your desired threading policy
  public PostProcExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize,
      long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
    super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue);
  }

  @Override
  protected <T> RunnableFuture<T> newTaskFor(Callable<T> callable) {
    return new FutureTask<T>(callable) {
      @Override
      protected void done()
      {
        if(!isCancelled()) try {
          processResult(get());
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
          throw new AssertionError("on complete task", ex);
        } catch(ExecutionException ex) {
          // no result available
        }
      }
    };
  }

  protected void processResult(Object o)
  {
    System.out.println("Result "+o);// do your post-processing here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_NUMBER));` to create service 
and use guava [ListenableFuture](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained) for parsing result immidiatly also you can wtite your bike for Listen future result.

```
ListeningExecutorService service = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));
ListenableFuture<Explosion> explosion = service.submit(new Callable<Explosion>() {
  public Explosion call() {
    return pushBigRedButton();
  }
});
Futures.addCallback(explosion, new FutureCallback<Explosion>() {
  // we want this handler to run immediately after we push the big red button!
  public void onSuccess(Explosion explosion) {
    walkAwayFrom(explosion);
  }
  public void onFailure(Throwable thrown) {
    battleArchNemesis(); // escaped the explosion!
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [ExecutorCompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html). This way you can get the result of the `Callable`(s) as soon as they are ready. The `take` method of the completion service blocks waiting for each tasks to be done.

Here is an example from the java doc:

```
void solve(Executor e,
            Collection<Callable<Result>> solvers)
     throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
     CompletionService<Result> ecs
         = new ExecutorCompletionService<Result>(e);
     for (Callable<Result> s : solvers)
         ecs.submit(s);
     int n = solvers.size();
     for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
         Result r = ecs.take().get();
         if (r != null)
             use(r);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ExecutorCompletionService** to implement it.

The following steps can help you some.

1. Populate the number of available processors using **Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()**. Let's keep the value in variable availableProcessors.
2. Initilize ExecutorService, like **service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(availableProcessors)**
3. Initialize ExecutorCompletionService, assume the result from Callable is an Integer Array Integer[], **ExecutorCompletionService completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService(service)**
4. Use **completionService.submit** to submit the task.
5. Use **completionService.take().get()** to get each result of a task (callable).

Based on the above steps you can get the results of all callable, and do some business you would like to.